# Do I fill out 8606?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I converted $100000 from rollover ira to Roth IRA. On 1099 R the distribution code is 7, not 2 because I am older than 60.
Do I need to file form 8606 or not?

Comment: Hopefully you either knew that you will need to pay income tax on that rollover or it was all after-tax contributions (which would be unusual in a non-Roth IRA).

Comment: Yes. I knew about tax and paid estimated tax in 2021.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do, if you want to properly report the conversion. Code 7 is "normal distribution", meaning the amounts distributed should be added to your income unless you report an indirect rollover or a conversion. See the "Who must file" section in the [instructions](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i8606#en_US_2021_publink25399ed0e169):

> ...
>
> You converted an amount from a traditional, SEP, or SIMPLE IRA to a Roth IRA in 2021.
> ...